# How to import contacts and opportunity records using npsp data import wizard

Tags: csv, npsp, data-import

I am trying to upload contact that has opportunity in salesforce using npsp data import wizard. but when I try to upload my data, it successfully uploaded but when I click the opportunity record , the opportunity record is not related to the contact. What should be the correct way of creating a template for contact that has opportunity.

Regards,

Danryl